# iphone create pdf from set of images

Tags: iphone, image, pdf

I have set of few images in documents directory of my project. I want a pdf file created in my iPhone app in documents directory itself from those images. I mean pdf with multiple images.
I am able to find create a pdf for a single image but not able to find any reference code to create pdf file of multiple images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load each image in an off-screen `UIWebView`. Then do the following for each image-

```
            CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792); //default PDF size
            CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil); //pdfContext is the CGContextRef of the PDF document
            //turn PDF upsidedown   
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;    
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, r.size.height);   
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);   
            CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);  
            [self.webView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];    
            CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);
```

This way, each image will end up on one page of the PDF.

Comment: I have solved it using create a page, then writing content on current context and then ending page. Repeating this process create multipage pdf document.